# Use Ubuntu Frame to implement "apps"

Tags: ssh, touchscreen, kiosk

Currently I have Ubuntu Frame running `wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk` displaying the Home Assistant webpage on a touch screen x86 machine.  I'd like to have a way "swap apps" from the touchscreen, and have it return after X amount of idle time.  Apps here being either loading a different web address or opening other snaps.

Home Assistant is capable of running ssh commands and I guess I could implement it that way, but I thought there may be a nicer way to accomplish this.